# Printing outline-regexp and outline-heading-alist

Tags: outline

I have a minor mode that changes the values of `outline-regexp` and `outline-heading-alist`.  And want a way for the minor mode to display the value on request by the user, without forcing the user to call the outline related commands directly.

How can I have a neat way to print the information in `outline-regexp` and `outline-heading-alist` ?

Comment: Print where? In what context? Interactively, the "neatest" way is `C-h v outline-regexp`.

Comment: I have a minor mode that changes the variables.  And I want a way for the user to print the updated ones by calling an interactive  function provided by the minor mode.  Things would be printed to the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: Then use `(message "%S" outline-regexp)`.

Comment: And you should still update your question with the extra information.

Comment: How about `outline-heading-alist` ?  Is there a neat way to show Heading and associated level ?